# Remote debugging threads with different debuggers

Tags: java, multithreading, remote-debugging

I have an application which is scheduler running different threads.
The application may load new Runnable classes and run them.
Currently the application is in production, that is it's running on remote server.

My team consists of 3 people developing Runnable classes.
When the class is ready, it's uploaded to server and loaded to scheduler.

I would like to give my team the ability to debug specific threads.
That is: person A may debug threads of Runnable A, B-B, and so on.

Giving them the full access to the remote JVM is not a solution, because
the developers are not allowed to see the system core, and each others solutions.

So my question is: how to allow multiple remote debugging with thread specific connections?

Preferable IDE: Eclipse

**EDIT:**

It's possible to connect remotely to specific thread with jdb
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html

Here is an example: http://www.itec.uni-klu.ac.at/~harald/CSE/Content/debugging.html
1) Find your thread with jdb threads
2) Put breakpoint and enter the wanted thread

Still the security issue stays.
One solution was to compile protected code without debug symbols, but it will only protect the core, allow seeing each other's threads.
So, next step - digging Security Manager. Maybe there's privilege layer suitable for my situation.

Comment: create a simple web application in server system, with simple file upload, download

Comment: These abilities are implemented already as part of the server system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've got a good answer to your question, but let's see how it pans out.

As I understand it you want to allow different developers to debug their class alone, and their class runs as a thread as part of a single Java process.

On the face of it that sort of runs counter to the nature of debugging in that normally you have access to everything in the process. I don't imagine that Java is any different to any other language in this respect (I'm no Java programmer).

So how about running the classes in separate Java processes. That way I presume the standard Eclipse tools would allow each developer to remote attach and debug their class.

However I presume that these classes need to interact with each other in some way, otherwise you wouldn't be asking your question in the first place. And running each class in a separate process (JVM) sounds like a bad thing as far as interaction is concerned.

So how about a different form of interaction where tbe process boundary between each class doesn't really matter that much? You could look at using [JCSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCSP) which, as far as I can tell, doesn't really care if two threads are in the same process or not.

It's a completely different interaction model, based solely on synchronous message passing. You get some nice fringe benefits - scalability is suddenly no longer a massive problem, and it allows you to dodge many pitfalls normally associated with multithreaded programs (deadlock, etc). However if you've already written a large amount of code, adopting JCSP is probably a significant rewrite.

Is that anywhere near the mark? Good luck.

Comment: Currently splitting the system, as described, will take time.
But I want to tell you: Thanks! Next time I'll take your answer into account.